# Notify OSD config on vivid vervet

Tags: package-management, ppa, notification, 15.04, notify-osd

I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet today and was annoyed, but unsurprised, to see that notify OSD was updated and restored to its default, limited, functionality.

The thing is, the patched version of `notify-osd` and its respective configuration tool don't appear to be packaged yet for Ubuntu 15.04. Following [the guide for 14.04/14.10](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/customize-on-screen-notification-ubuntu-1404/) didn't work (not that I really expected it to), and I'm looking for a way to make notify OSD pretty again.

I'm usually an Arch Linux user, so the whole concept of a dist-upgrade is kind of foreign to me. Because the packages aren't packaged, does that mean the binaries are incompatible? Why don't the PPAs for 14.10 work? Can I download and install the required packages somehow without the system complaining at me?

Comment: You'll have to contact the PPA maintainer or wait until a package for 15.04 is aviable, if it is ever.

Comment: @xangua so you're saying that 14.10 binaries won't even have a chance of working on 15.04? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: In Ubuntu you do not install packages from diferent releases, but you can try if you like and test it yourself.  I would guess if you try to force install you might have some conflic issues since the 14.10 software version is lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't comment on the previous answer (lack of rep), but to add on to Kam's answer above, you can download the `notify-osd` .deb file from [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/leolik/leolik/ubuntu/pool/main/n/notify-osd/), for me I just installed the daily one.

Run `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb` and you'll find that it'll immediately work with your existing NotifyOSDConfig installed. This will "downgrade" `notify-osd` (as shown in output), and therefore you will need to blacklist `notify-osd` from auto-upgrades like the other answer mentioned.

Comment: @uglytoaster do mark it as accepted answered if it has answered your question!

Answer (score 1):

There was an update from ppa:leolik/leolik today and it works like a charm on 15.04, so add this repo and problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'll add the ppa back into my sources. The question was already resolved though, since I was mostly looking for a way to downgrade notify-osd and keep it downgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the 14.10 package, and it works out of the box, however, you have to use use the --force option to install it, and you must bloacklist notify-osd in synaptic (prevent future updates) or it's gonna reinstall the official package - untill the ppa is updated for vivid that is.

Also, apt-get dist-upgrade does not upgrade the distribution. It's just like a normal upgrade, but it will also install new packages. Upgrading to a newer distribution is completely different (oh, and since we're talking about that: do not do a dist-upgrade from the terminal if you install that package in force not to reinstall the official package: use synaptic or the update manager instead).

Comment: `dist-upgrade` is `upgrade`, but it also removes packages if it's necessary to upgrade.